# Access SQL join expression is not supported

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using access to run a query but it is saying join operation is not supported. I've checked the syntax and it seems fine. Can anyone please help me understand why this is failing:

```
SELECT
   d.uid,
   md_20180901.monthval,
   md_20180801.monthval,
   md_20180701.val 
FROM
   (
(data as d 
      LEFT JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               md.* 
            FROM
               monthdata md 
            WHERE
               md.monthval = #01/09/2018# 
         )
         as md_20180901 
         ON d.UID = md_20180901.dataUID 
         AND md_20180901.monthval = #01/09/2018# ) 
      LEFT JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               md.* 
            FROM
               monthdata md 
            WHERE
               md.monthval = #01/08/2018# 
         )
         as md_20180801 
         ON d.UID = md_20180801.dataUID 
         AND md_20180801.monthval = #01/08/2018#
   )
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            md.* 
         FROM
            monthdata md 
         WHERE
            md.monthval = #01/07/2018# 
      )
      as md_20180701 
      ON d.UID = md_20180701.dataUID 
      AND md_20180701.monthval = #01/07/2018#
WHERE
   d.UID = "5B51141D";
```

For context, this is my tables

**data** table

```
ID
UID
MYNAME
```

**monthdata** table

```
ID
DATAUID
MONTHVAL
VAL
```

Comment: Consider even a crosstab query: `TRANSFORM SUM(NZ(md.val)) AS SumOfVal SELECT d.uid FROM data d LEFT JOIN monthdata md ON d.UID = md.DATAUID GROUP BY d.uid PIVOT md.monthval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access only supports literals in join expressions when the expression has been surrounded by parentheses:

```
SELECT
   d.uid,
   md_20180901.monthval,
   md_20180801.monthval,
   md_20180701.val 
FROM
   (
(data as d 
      LEFT JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               md.* 
            FROM
               monthdata md 
            WHERE
               md.monthval = #01/09/2018# 
         )
         as md_20180901 
         ON (d.UID = md_20180901.dataUID 
         AND md_20180901.monthval = #01/09/2018#) ) 
      LEFT JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               md.* 
            FROM
               monthdata md 
            WHERE
               md.monthval = #01/08/2018# 
         )
         as md_20180801 
         ON (d.UID = md_20180801.dataUID 
         AND md_20180801.monthval = #01/08/2018#)
   )
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            md.* 
         FROM
            monthdata md 
         WHERE
            md.monthval = #01/07/2018# 
      )
      as md_20180701 
      ON (d.UID = md_20180701.dataUID 
      AND md_20180701.monthval = #01/07/2018#)
WHERE
   d.UID = "5B51141D";
```

However, you're doing something weird here. You're also comparing inside subqueries. Remove those:

```
SELECT
   d.uid,
   md_20180901.monthval,
   md_20180801.monthval,
   md_20180701.val 
FROM
(
(data as d 
      LEFT JOIN
         monthdata as md_20180901 
         ON (d.UID = md_20180901.dataUID 
         AND md_20180901.monthval = #01/09/2018#) ) 
      LEFT JOIN
         monthdata as md_20180801 
         ON (d.UID = md_20180801.dataUID 
         AND md_20180801.monthval = #01/08/2018#)
   )
   LEFT JOIN
      monthdata as md_20180701 
      ON (d.UID = md_20180701.dataUID 
      AND md_20180701.monthval = #01/07/2018#)
WHERE
   d.UID = "5B51141D";
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm using the second query but it seems to return uid 5b51141d in the left column but no results in the other three columns, when I was expecting it to return the date for example. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: I would need to see your exact source data. Comparing to date literals generally is a bad plan, because those get implemented as a double in Access, and can contain fractions of a second without ever displaying them, even on linked tables where the source doesn't even support them. Try `Abs(md_20180801.monthval - #01/09/2018#) < 1` as a comparison, if that works, your month values are inaccurately stored

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing all the unnecessary parts and making it simpler. Example:

```
            SELECT
               md.* 
            FROM
               monthdata md 
            WHERE
               md.monthval = #01/09/2018# 
         )
         as md_20180901 
         ON d.UID = md_20180901.dataUID 
         AND md_20180901.monthval = #01/09/2018#
```

can be simplified:

```
(SELECT val FROM monthdata WHERE monthval=#01/09/2018#) md_20180901
ON d.UID=md_20180901.dataUID
```

You do not need to repeat table names unless there is a field name conflict.
You do not need to assign aliases that will never be used (in fact I generally only assign aliases if I am using the same table twice).
You do not need to add `monthval` on filtering on the `ON` since you are already doing it in `WHERE`.
The only field you are actually collecting is `val` (`monthval` is effectively a fixed value since you are filtering by a specific date) so don't use `*`.

Clean up your query and try adding one `monthval` at a time and see what happens.

Comment: I'm struggling to get their of those to run, syntax error in union